# How to show the diff panel when li click

Tags: c#, asp.net, panel

I want to show the different panel when i click the HTML list item. Am using the menu with list item list item having four list and am also having four panel. i want to show the panel when click the li menu..

My partial code is here..

```
  <ul id="menulist1"> 
     <li><a href="#">General Info</a></li> // show pan_genral
     <li><a href="#">Contact Info</a></li> // show pan_contact
     <li><a href="#">Job Info</a></li>     // show pan_job
     <li><a href="#">Qualification</a></li>// show pan_Quali
  </ul>


 <asp:Panel ID="pan_contact" runat="server" Height="388px" Visible="false">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="2px" cellspacing="4px"  width="100%">
   <tr>
       <td>contact</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </asp:Panel>
```

please help me to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the onclick function for the `li` and send the id of the panel to show, as this code:

```
    <ul id="menulist1">
       <li><a href="#" onclick="showPanel("pan_genral")">General Info</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" onclick="showPanel("pan_contact")">ContactInfo</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" onclick="showPanel("pan_job")">Job Info</a></li> 
       <li><a href="#" onclick="showPanel("pan_Quali")">Qualification</a></li> 
    </ul> 

     <script>
        function showPanel(panId)
       {
          var panel=document.getElementById(panId)
          panel.style.display="";
       }    
     </script>
```

for the panel, don't use `visible=false`  but use: `style="display:none"`

```
    <asp:Panel ID="pan_contact" runat="server" Height="388px" style="display:none">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="2px" cellspacing="4px"  width="100%"> 
           <tr> 
             <td>contact</td> 
           </tr> 
        </table> 
     </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a bit of javascript, but note that if you are using a master page, the ContentPlaceholderID gets prepended to the panel ID. For instance, if your ContentPlaceholderID is `MainContent`, you will need something like this:

```
function showPanel(panelId) {
    var panel = document.getElementById("MainContent_" + panelId);
    panel.style.display = 'block';
}
```

But, like previous answer states, use `style="display:none"` instead of `Visible=false` in your panel for this to work.

If you want the bullets to also trigger the panel, move `onclick` to your `li` tag.

```
<li onclick="showPanel('pan_contact')">Contact Info</li>
```